# DAX like calulation in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL table like following

| SN | name | status | input# | val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sam | OnHold | 20 | 500 |
| 2 | Sam | OnHold | 22 | 545 |
| 3 | Sam | NotOnHold | 25 | 600 |
| 4 | Sam | NotOnHold | 18 | 400 |
| 5 | Alan | OnHold | 20 | 500 |
| 6 | Alan | NotOnHold | 22 | 500 |
| 7 | Joseph | OnHold | 18 | 643 |
| 8 | Joseph | OmHold | 23 | 543 |
| 9 | Elis | NotOnHold | 21 | 499 |
| 10 | Elis | NotOnhold | 27 | 400 |

I want to write a SQL code that would count the total number of instances the `status='OnHold'` by name and return that value by name in a calculated column, like following

| SN | name | status | input# | val | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sam | OnHold | 20 | 500 | 2 |
| 2 | Sam | OnHold | 22 | 545 | 2 |
| 3 | Sam | NotOnHold | 25 | 600 | 2 |
| 4 | Sam | NotOnHold | 18 | 400 | 2 |
| 5 | Alan | OnHold | 20 | 500 | 1 |
| 6 | Alan | NotOnHold | 22 | 500 | 1 |
| 7 | Joseph | OnHold | 18 | 643 | 1 |
| 8 | Joseph | OmHold | 23 | 543 | 1 |
| 9 | Elis | NotOnHold | 21 | 499 | NULL |
| 10 | Elis | NotOnhold | 27 | 400 | NULL |

I can do the following by doing a count first and then by doing a join like following

```
declare @t1 TABLE (SN int, name varchar(10), status varchar(10), input# int, val int)
INSERT INTO @t1
Select SN, name,status,input#,val
from
(
VALUES 
(1, 'Sam', 'OnHold', 20, 500), 
(2, 'Sam', 'OnHold', 22, 545), 
(3, 'Sam', 'NotOnHold', 25, 600), 
(4, 'Sam', 'NotOnHold', 18, 400), 
(5, 'Alan', 'OnHold', 20, 500), 
(6, 'Alan', 'NotOnHold', 22, 500), 
(7, 'Joseph', 'OnHold', 18, 643), 
(8, 'Joseph', 'OmHold', 23, 543), 
(9, 'Elis', 'NotOnHold', 21, 499), 
(10, 'Elis', 'NotOnhold', 27, 400)
) t (SN, name,status,input#,val)

declare @t2 TABLE (name varchar(10), count int)
INSERT INTO @t2
select DISTINCT(name), COUNT(name) from @t1 where [status]='OnHold' GROUP BY name

select a.*, b.count from @t1 a LEFT JOIN @t2 b ON a.name=b.name
```

But is it possible to reach to the outcome without performing a join at all. It is a simplified version of my issue that I am currently facing. Join has been extremely expensive for this transformation.

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of joining an aggregate, you can use a "window function" to calculate an aggregate over a "window" of rows, like this:

```
declare @t1 TABLE (SN int, name varchar(10), status varchar(10), input# int, val int)
INSERT INTO @t1
Select SN, name,status,input#,val
from
(
VALUES 
(1, 'Sam', 'OnHold', 20, 500), 
(2, 'Sam', 'OnHold', 22, 545), 
(3, 'Sam', 'NotOnHold', 25, 600), 
(4, 'Sam', 'NotOnHold', 18, 400), 
(5, 'Alan', 'OnHold', 20, 500), 
(6, 'Alan', 'NotOnHold', 22, 500), 
(7, 'Joseph', 'OnHold', 18, 643), 
(8, 'Joseph', 'OmHold', 23, 543), 
(9, 'Elis', 'NotOnHold', 21, 499), 
(10, 'Elis', 'NotOnhold', 27, 400)
) t (SN, name,status,input#,val)



select a.*, sum(case when status = 'OnHold' then 1 else null end) over (partition by name) count
from @t1 a 
order by name
```

outpus

```
SN          name       status     input#      val         count
----------- ---------- ---------- ----------- ----------- -----------
5           Alan       OnHold     20          500         1
6           Alan       NotOnHold  22          500         1
9           Elis       NotOnHold  21          499         NULL
10          Elis       NotOnhold  27          400         NULL
7           Joseph     OnHold     18          643         1
8           Joseph     OmHold     23          543         1
1           Sam        OnHold     20          500         2
2           Sam        OnHold     22          545         2
3           Sam        NotOnHold  25          600         2
4           Sam        NotOnHold  18          400         2
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

(10 rows affected)
```

Comment: David can't thank you enough for this awesome trick. 300 seconds with what I had vs 20 seconds with your trick.Did not know about the window function, learnt from you today. Thanks again !!!

Comment: Curious why you chose `sum(case...then 1` vs `count(case` I'm not aware of any perf difference, is it just personal preference? Also why `else null` is that not redundant?

Comment: I routinely use SUM with CASE as it's more explicit about NULL handling and add the `else` clause in the CASE as that's a general pattern that's useful for lots of similar problems.